# react native google places undefined is not an object when searching

Tags: react-native, google-places-api

I have imported the example from the npm page but it fails everytime.

I can display the auto complete input no issue. But as soon as I search it crashes.

[image: Error message after searching]

I have no clue why it won't work and I'm not the most proficient in react-native...

Here is my place picker component

```
import React from 'react';

import
{
View,
Image,
Text
} from 'react-native';

import { GooglePlacesAutocomplete } from 'react-native-google-places-autocomplete';

const API_KEY = 'AIza____REMOVED____qDNtmo';

const PlacePicker = (props) =>
{
return (
    <GooglePlacesAutocomplete
                placeholder='Event Location'
                minLength={2} // minimum length of text to search
                autoFocus={false}
                // Can be left out for default return key https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput.html#returnkeytype
                listViewDisplayed='auto'    // true/false/undefined
                fetchDetails={true}
                renderDescription={row => row.description} // custom description render
                onPress={(data, details = null) => { // 'details' is provided when fetchDetails = true
                  console.warn(data, details);

                }}
                textInputProps={{
                  onChangeText: (text) => { /*console.warn(text)*/ }
                }}
                getDefaultValue={() => ''}

                query={{
                  // available options: https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/autocomplete
                  key: API_KEY,
                  language: 'en', // language of the results
                  types: 'geocode' // default: 'geocode'
                }}

                styles={{
                  textInputContainer: {
                    backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)',
                    borderTopWidth: 0,
                    borderBottomWidth:0,
                  },
                  description: {
                    fontWeight: 'bold',
                  },
                  textInput: {
                  marginLeft: 22,
                  marginRight: 0,
                  height: 38,
                  color: '#5d5d5d',
                  fontSize: 16,
                },
                  predefinedPlacesDescription: {
                    color: '#1faadb'
                  }
                }}
                value={() => {}}
                onChangeText={() => {}}
                renderLeftButton={()  => <Text style={{ marginTop: 12, marginLeft:16, fontSize: 18 }}> Location </Text>}
                nearbyPlacesAPI='GooglePlacesSearch' // Which API to use: GoogleReverseGeocoding or GooglePlacesSearch
                GoogleReverseGeocodingQuery={{
                  // available options for GoogleReverseGeocoding API : https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro
                }}
                GooglePlacesSearchQuery={{
                  // available options for GooglePlacesSearch API : https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search
                  rankby: 'distance',
                  types: 'food'
                }}

                filterReverseGeocodingByTypes={['locality', 'administrative_area_level_3']} // filter the reverse geocoding results by types - ['locality', 'administrative_area_level_3'] if you want to display only cities
                debounce={200} // debounce the requests in ms. Set to 0 to remove debounce. By default 0ms.

              />
);
}

export default PlacePicker;
```

I have no clue why I can't get this to work.  I can see the API call was sent to the Google Places API when I look in the developer API dashboard.